# Asp redirects to Login even though Request.IsAuthenticated = true (using windows authentication)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-membership

I have a webapplication, that I have running in the WAN as well as in the LAN. The same code runs in separate web apps.
In the WAN I have configured it to use forms authentication. It works seamlessly.
However the LAN app is configured to use windows authentication.

What happens now, is that the website says "Hello DOMAIN\TestUser" which shows, that

- Request.IsAuthenticated must be true
- User.Identity.Name is set to the correct user

**However**: I'm always finding myself on the "Account/Login" page.
For clarification: my Login page is using a general layout-template that performs the 'Request.IsAuthenticated' mentioned above.

**My question**: Why am I being redirected to the login page, when the authentication evidently succeeded? And what do I do to make it work? :)

This, I guess is the crucial part of my configuration:

```
  <system.web>
    <authentication mode="Windows">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>
    <membership defaultProvider="SimpleMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="SimpleMembershipProvider" type="WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleMembershipProvider, WebMatrix.WebData" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
  </system.web>
```

The IIS for this web app is setup with Windows Authentication enabled and all other methods of Authentication disabled.

(I'm using ASP.Net MVC 4)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution here:
http://martinnormark.com/asp-net-mvc-3-windows-authentication-problem-redirects-to-account-login
after spending a few more hours googling...

The Answer is luckily very simple:
Add these two properties to your app settings:

```
  <appSettings>
    <add key="autoFormsAuthentication" value="false" />
    <add key="enableSimpleMembership" value="false"/>
  </appSettings>
```

Looks like very bad practice to me... but hey, it does the job.

Comment: Not asking you to "approve of" my answer, but if you're just switching from forms to windows auth, why **add** to you web.config, just remove instead no?

Answer (score 1):

Encountered this before and have to compare my local IIS deployment, where my project runs just fine, with that of what was deployed on a server. It turns out there are extra DLLs **that should not have been deployed**. My scenario though is a bit different than yours. The project was working on my local machine but not on a LAN environment. The extra files that needed to be removed:

- WebMatrix.Data.dll
- WebMatrix.WebData.dll

I hope it's the same case as yours, that is one hard deployment issue to catch.

Comment: Unfortunately that wasn't it. Maybe help for someone else though.
How did you even figure that out?? :)

Comment: My first step in debugging deployment issue is to check the config, then the deployed files. And if I got those reference issues, I started removing files and bringing them back in, same thing with any weird issues. Old school but works faster than Googling around. If all things fails then that's the time I hit Google.

Answer (score 0):

Taking out the `<forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" />` line and the `<membership />` section might help?

Which would leave you with:

```
<system.web>
    <authentication mode="Windows"></authentication>        
</system.web>
```

Comment: Thanks. But that's not actually, what I'm aiming for.
Since the Login is predefined as <forms loginUrl="~/Login.aspx" />, removing the tag just results in a 404 error, since I don't have a Login.aspx